# Sticky header in the middle

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, sticky

I'm trying to make a **sticky header** within a **mid region**. It should stick to the top when the page is scrolled over the **`<ul id="scroll-list"></ul>`** element. But it must not stick on the top when the page is scrolled over **`<div id="stop-sticky"></div>`**

I have come close by following the **solution of @izulito.**

But **problem** I've seen in this updated solution is that the header element seem to **move to it's original position**, which I verified by `console.log($('#header').offset().top);` , after scrolling to **`<div id="stop-sticky"></div>`**. It makes the header div to flash  at the transition.

> **I want a smooth scroll in which header should disappear and reappear along with the scroll.**
>
> ```js
> $( document ).ready(function() {
>  var actualPosition = $('#header').offset().top;
>  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
>  console.log($('#header').offset().top);
>   if($(window).scrollTop() > $('#stop-sticky').offset().top) {
>       $('#header').addClass('nonstiky');
>     } else {
>           $('#header').removeClass('nonstiky');}
>  });
> });
> ```
>
> ```css
> #summary {
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 300px;
>     background: #ccc;
>   }
>
>   #header {
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 60px;
>     background: #fcc;
>     position: sticky;
>     top: 10px;
>   }
>     
>     #header.nonstiky {
>       position: relative
>       }
>
>   #scroll-list {
>     height: 500px;
>     background: #cc1;
>   }
>     #stop-sticky {
>     height: 1000px;
>     background: #c01;
>   }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <body>
>  <div id="summary">Summary</div>
>  <div id="header">Header</div>
>  <ul id="scroll-list"></ul>
>         <div id="stop-sticky"></div>
> </body>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code out. I added a class to your header when you scroll pass the stop-sticky id.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var actualPosition = $('#header').offset().top;
 $(window).scroll(function (event) {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > $('#stop-sticky').offset().top) {
      $('#header').addClass('nonstiky');
    } else {
          $('#header').removeClass('nonstiky');}
 });
});
```

```css
#summary {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
  }

  #header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #fcc;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
  }
    
    #header.nonstiky {
      position: relative
      }

  #scroll-list {
    height: 500px;
    background: #cc1;
  }
    #stop-sticky {
    height: 1000px;
    background: #c01;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="summary">Summary</div>
 <div id="header">Header</div>
 <ul id="scroll-list"></ul>
        <div id="stop-sticky"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: So do you want header to disappear when you hit stop sticky?